# Ballistic acceleration in low $g$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, projectile

A simpler question please: What is expected if a bullet were to be shot straight up on the Moon or Mars, vs. what the same caliber bullet shot with the same trajectory on earth? I'm distinguishing between a ballistic effect and a rocket's steady thrust.

Intuitively this seems like it should accelerate faster in low/no $g$ environments, but I'd like to know if this is not the case.

Comment: for some context, i'm thinking that the jumps of apollo astronauts on the moon 'appeared' to be slower ascending in-line with their descents, and that this is analogous to ballistics. trying to understand why a jump up in low G might be slower than the same motion (same leg-muscle power), and more net 'weight' on the earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the propellant for the bullet is not affected by the different environment, the bullet will accelerate slightly faster due to the (much) thinner atmosphere. There is no other difference up to the gun's muzzle.
Beyond that, the bullet will decelerate slower, due to both lower gravitational acceleration and thin atmosphere.

The maximum height is inversely proportional to the gravitational acceleration. On the Moon, expect it to go slightly over 6x higher than on Earth. For example, at 300 m/s that is ~28 km high.

Comment: The force from the exploding charge must first overcome local gravity downward force on the bullet, and with the left-over force, accelerate the bullet upward. More left-over force on Mars and even more on Moon.  Absolutely microscopic effect...

Comment: a microscopic effect toward the side of increased acceleration, yes?

Comment: ...meaning that there should be no reason why the acceleration would be less in a low G environment than on earth. just wanted to clarify. thanks